# Selenium Webdriver c# select a specific table cell when the cell is present

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have launched & navigated to a popup search page, where I select some search criteria. I then select a search button and a grid/table of entries is displayed. The table will only be populated with entries if the search criteria has found entries based on the input given (Its basically a hotel rate search, if you look for a hotel in a certain area it will return rates. No hotels available = no rates).

So I have started these lines of code like this:

```
// Selects the cell you require from the table grid (tr=row td=cell nth-child=number down)
mWebDriver.SelectElement(By.CssSelector("#grd_ResultsRateByRoom tr td.Selectable"));
if (tableCells == 0)
    throw new System.Exception("No rate available");
```

Now all I want to do is return an alternate line of code to click any valid entry if there is an entry displaying (I have already defined a class for `ClickElementById`, but using the standard `tableCell.click;` on the end of this does not function correctly?

[image]

Comment: Thanks @user1177636 , I have just realised that I need 10+ reputation points to post images. Would help if I could attach a screenshot for you....

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. . . . The screenshot is here: http://i.imgur.com/eE52XmX.png (Let me know what further info would be helpful and I will update the post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have solved it (using both the `FindElement` with `By.Xpath` and `By.CssSelector` methods).

One that worked best was:

```
mWebDriver.SelectElement(By.CssSelector("#grd_ResultsRateByRoom tr td.Selectable")).Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using XPath to locate the specific cell. You can locate it via FirePath extension for FireFox

Comment: Thank you! Would vote your answer up but as a noob i dont have any priviledge to do this :-)